# Replace/update all the import statements from all the files using intelliJ IDEA or eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, import, upgrade

The requirement is to use upgraded version of a library in my existing code. And in the new version of the library, the package names have changed. It will be a tedious task to go and update the import statements in all locations (min 100+ files) with the new package name.

Is there a way to do this effectively in IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has a feature specifically for that: [Migrate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrate.html).

The Migrate refactoring lets you easily switch between the old packages and classes used in your project and the new ones. IntelliJ IDEA comes with the default migration map.

[image: migrate]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), assuming that you want to replace `import old.package` with `import new.package`:

```
find /path/to/project \
    -iname \*.java \
    -type f \
    -exec sed -i "s/import old.package/import new.package/g" {} \;
```